# Android ArcMenu. Place image on 2 different arcmenues

Tags: java, android

Im have 2 arcmenues on my layout and Im need to place 2 different images on 2 different arcmenues. Arcmenues looks like photo frame. Plus ("+") sign is image that im replace with loaded image from camera or photo gallery.

http://imageshack.com/a/img901/3791/kXFgyC.jpg

The problem is that when arcmenu initializing, it's using arcmenu template. So, "plus" image is defined here as ImageView. When Im loading photo, its placing only in first arcmenu, becouse there are 1 ImageView in the arcmenu template.

ArcMenu initialization code:

```
 public void initArcMenu(ArcMenu menu, int[] ITEM_DRAWABLES)
{
    final int itemCount = ITEM_DRAWABLES.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
        ImageView item = new ImageView(this);
        item.setImageResource(ITEM_DRAWABLES[i]);

        final int position = i;

        menu.addItem(item, new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(position == 0)
                {
                    Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(pickPhoto , 1);//pick photo from gallery
                }
                if(position == 1)
                {
                    Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(takePicture, 0);//capture from camera
                }
        }
        });
    }
}
```

onActivityResult code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

    switch(requestCode) {
        case 0:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) imageReturnedIntent.getExtras().get("data");
                mPhoto.setImageBitmap(photo);
            }

            break;
        case 1:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                mPhoto.setImageURI(selectedImage);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```